# Why is my substring causing an error in my program?

Tags: java

When I run this program, an error comes up, saying that it is due to "String.substring(int, int)line: not available. However, it outputs the correct answer (with a number of 123 and a target of 2, the final should be 35). Any help would be great, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Math{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) { 
            System.out.println("Please enter your number:");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String number= input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your target:");
            int target= input.nextInt();
            // input.close();


            String outcome= "0";
            long final = Long.parseLong(outcome);

            for (int h=0; h<=((number.length())-target+1); h++) {
                String result = number.substring(h, (target+h));   
                long output = Long.valueOf(result);                    

                final = final + result;

                    System.out.println(final);
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a variable called `final`- It's a reserved keyword. Beyond that you're trying to add a `String` to a `long`

Comment: `final`  is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here:

- `final` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), and cannot be a variable name. You must rename it
- You are trying to add a `String` to a `long` in the line:

  `final = final + result;`
- You have a index out of bounds error when you call `substring`. You are looping one more time then necessary. Change `<=` to `<`:

Code:

```
String outcome= "0";
long finalVar = Long.parseLong(outcome);

for (int h=0; h<((number.length())-target+1); h++) {
     String result = number.substring(h, (target+h));   
     long output = Long.valueOf(result);                    
     finalVar = finalVar + output;

}         
System.out.println(finalVar);
```

***Input/Output:***

```
Please enter your number:
123
Please enter your target:
2
35
```